# React Hooks useEffect to call a prop callback from useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, race-condition, use-effect

I'm trying to make a general-purpose infinite scroller with React Hooks (and the ResearchGate React Intersection Observer). The idea is that a parent will pass down a mapped JSX array of data and a callback that will asynchronously get more data for that array, and when the intersection observer fires because you've scrolled down enough to reveal the loading icon, the callback gets called and more data is loaded.

It works well enough, except one thing: esLint tells me that because I'm calling the getMore function (from the props) inside a useEffect, it must be a dependency of that effect. But because in the parent's callback I'm accessing its data array's length, that array must be a dependency of useCallback there. And then that callback modifies the array.

TL;DR: I'm getting race conditions that cause the async callback to trigger multiple times when it shouldn't, because the callback function reference is changing and then being passed down to the thing that's calling it.

Here's some code to clarify.

The callback in the parent:

```
const loadData = useCallback(async () => {
    if (hasMore) {
        const startAmount = posts.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            posts.push(`I am post number ${i + startAmount}.`);
            await delay(100);
        }
        setPosts([...posts]);
        setHasMore(posts.length < 100);
    }
}, [posts, hasMore]);
```

posts and hasMore are just state variables, with posts being passed down as the data array in props to the child. That function is being passed to the child in props, which has this (getMore is the destructured prop for the callback, isLoading is just a boolean state variable):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
        (async () => {
            await getMore();
            setIsLoading(false);
        })();
    }
}, [isLoading, getMore]);
```

I'm setting isLoading to true to trigger the effect; but it's also triggering because getMore's reference changes when the parent loads data and the function memoizes. That shouldn't happen. I could just disable esLint for that line, but I assume there's a better solution, and I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: Why would the `getMore` reference change? Can you share the code where you define `getMore`?

Comment: I think the real problem is that you're using the isLoading bool to control the async data loading when it should be the other way around. You can make the async function its own function *outside* of useEffect and call it when you need it, i.e. when the intersectionObserver events fire. The async function would `setIsLoading(true)` at the beginning, then `setIsLoading(false)` at the end to control the `isLoading` variable.

Comment: @Khauri The problem is that state setters are async, and the observer can fire multiple times in a short period depending on how the user scrolls. So even if the function called by the observer calls `setIsLoading(true)` immediately, it can still get called again before the value is changed to `true`, so I still get duplicate calls :( ... or, at least I swear that's what happened when I tried that first. Yet now when I re-implement it, it works fine O_O I must have had an unknown bug before... can you post that as an official answer so I can accept it? :D

Comment: Hmm I've only used the IntersectionObserver once in my life, so I'm not all the way sure how it works. If you get a bug like that again, you might also want to look into [debouncing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/debouncing-in-javascript/). I'm kinda tired tbh. You should post your own solution and accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: don't use useEffect at all. Just call the loading function directly from the observer and have that set isLoading and call the callback rather than having isLoading trigger the callback.

```
const loadData = async (observerEntry) => {
    if (observerEntry.isIntersecting && !disabled && !isLoading) {
        setIsLoading(true);
        await getMore();
        setIsLoading(false);
    }
};
```